# convertToWorldSpace - cocos2d

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

- **convertToWorldSpace**

Hi, I'm not sure I understand how this works.
The api states that it converts local coordinate to world space.

Let' say I have three sprites. spriteA added to scene , and spriteB added to spriteA. And spriteC added to spriteB.

```
- Scene
    - spriteA
        - spriteB
            - spriteC
```

And I want to convert spriteC origin to world

If I do: `[self convertToWorldSpace:[spriteC CGPointZero]];`

or this: `[spriteA convertToWorldSpace:[spriteC CGPointZero]];`

or this: `[spriteB convertToWorldSpace:[spriteC CGPointZero]];`

or even `[spriteC convertToWorldSpace:[spriteC CGPointZero]];`

Shouldn't they all give the same answer since they are all transformed to world coordinates? Or do I go from one node space to parent node space ...until I get to world space.

what is the correct answer to see spriteC position in world coordinates?

Answer (score 4):

To find the world space origin on `spriteC`, you take the sprites parent, in this case `spriteB` and ask for the world space of its child:

```
[spriteB convertToWorldSpace:[spriteC CGPointZero]];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
[spriteC convertToWorldSpace:CGPointZero];
```

As Kazuki answer but CGPointZero is a global.

Answer (score 0):

```
[spriteC convertToWorldSpace:[spriteC CGPointZero]];
```

convertToWorldSpace: method converts one node space to parent node space ... until it gets to world space.